# Having trouble getting Target's ListRow on Worsheet_Change in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

So, I'm trying to get the `ListRow` from `Target`, but I seem to get errors non-stop. The goal is to upload changes done in the document to a server. Originally I looped through `ListRows` to upload the changes when the document was closed, but now the `ListObjects` have become so large that it takes too long to upload the arrays to the server. The faster way appears to simply upload changes as they happen.

I wrote a code below, and i get the error: invalid or unqualified reference.
There are a couple of functions I've omitted since they are working and are irrelevant to the issue.

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Dim CustomersConn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim CustomersCmd As ADODB.Command
        Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim lr As Excel.ListRow
        Dim Customers As Variant


        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(8)
        Set lo = ws.ListObjects("TCustomers")
        Set CustomersConn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set CustomersCmd = New ADODB.Command

        lr = .ListRow(Target.row - 5).Index


        CustomersConn.ConnectionString = SQLConStr

        CustomersConn.Open

        CustomersCmd.ActiveConnection = CustomersConn


        CustomersCmd.CommandText = _
        GetUpdateText( _
        Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Type").Range).Value, _
        Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Customer").Range).Value, _
        Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Name").Range).Value, _
        Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Contact").Range).Value, _
        Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Email").Range).Value, _
        Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Phone").Range).Value, _
        Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Corp").Range).Value)

        Debug.Print (CustomersCmd.CommandText)
CustomersConn.Close

Set CustomersConn = Nothing
Set lo = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set lr = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: `lr = .ListRow(Target.row - 5).Index` indicates that it should be inside a With Block.  Should it be `lr = lo.ListRow(Target.row - 5).Index`?

Comment: I expect @ScottCraner is correct, but notice he framed it as a question. You did not specify what line(s) throw an error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just now responding. So, he did indeed point to the line that causes the error, but the running the code with his correction returns a different error: 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Solved it! So, I need to use the Set function for lr in this case. So the line need to look like:

`Set lr = lo.ListRows(Target.row - 5)`

I am a fool.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! So, I need to use the Set function for lr in this case. So the line need to look like: `Set lr = lo.ListRows(Target.row - 5)` I am a fool.